# Why does my controller render the wrong view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance

I have two controllers, and one inherits from the other:

```
class FirstController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def show
   ...
  end
end

class SecondController < FirstController
  ...
  def show
   ...
  end
end
```

The views folder for the first controller contains the following files:

- views/first/show.html.erb
- views/first/show.js.erb

The views folder for the second controller contains only the HTML file:

- views/second/show.html.erb

Render or redirect are not being called within the controller's `show` methods.

When I call `SecondController#show` as `JS`, I expect `views/first/show.js.erb` to be rendered, but this is not happening. I get in response: `Rendered second/show.html.erb`.

If I remove the file `views/second/show.html.erb`, then there is no problem, and I get in response `Rendered first/show.js.erb`. Why is this happening?

What can I do to call the JS view of the parent controller in a non-explicit way like rendering `first/show`?

Comment: Can you show the code for your `show` methods? I suspect the `show` method in your `SecondController` doesn't call the `show` method that it overrode in the `FirstController`.

Comment: I think that's because views are not inherited in any way in Rails, which in my opinion is proper behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty weird.  This is just a shot in the dark, but what happens if in your second controller you explicitly tell it which file to render for JS?

```
class SecondController < FirstController
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render "first/show.js" }
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Then it goes right. But problem is that I can't do this, because I need folowing behaviour: If second/show.js file present then it rendering, If not, first/show.js rendering

Comment: Eh, you may need to do some really hacky stuff like File.exists?("#{Rails.root}/app/views/second.js.erb")